# openlayers3 move feature, does not work if not less than 3.14 versions

Tags: javascript, dictionary, gis, openlayers-3

I have a problem with version 3.14 and higher Openlayers3 this example to move Features does not work if not less than 3.14 versions, what should I do to work with the new versions?.

I'm trying to move characteristics of type circle in my project, I found an example of how to do it but does not work with the latest versions of openlayers3.

I hope your help thanks!

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({//Capas
                title: 'OSM',
                type: 'base',
                visible: true,
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-9777389, 5058721],
    zoom: 5
  })
});

function onDrawend() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    setActiveEditing(true);
    activeInteraction.setActive(false);
    document.getElementById('draw').value = 'select';
  }, 200);
}

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector()
});
vectorLayer.setMap(map);

var pointInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'Point',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource()
});
pointInteraction.setActive(false);
pointInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);

var lineInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'LineString',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource()
});
lineInteraction.setActive(false);
lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);

var polygonInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'Polygon',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource()
});
polygonInteraction.setActive(false);
polygonInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);

var circleInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'Circle',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource()
});
circleInteraction.setActive(false);
circleInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);

var rectangleInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'LineString',
  source: vectorLayer.getSource(),
  maxPoints: 2,
  geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
    if (!geometry) {
      geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    }
    var start = coordinates[0];
    var end = coordinates[1];
    geometry.setCoordinates([
      [start, [start[0], end[1]], end, [end[0], start[1]], start]
    ]);
    return geometry;
  }
});
rectangleInteraction.setActive(false);
rectangleInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);

var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  wrapX: false
});
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});
var translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});
var setActiveEditing = function(active) {
  selectInteraction.getFeatures().clear();
  selectInteraction.setActive(active);
  modifyInteraction.setActive(active);
  translateInteraction.setActive(active);
};
setActiveEditing(true);

var snapInteraction = new ol.interaction.Snap({
  source: vectorLayer.getSource()
});

map.getInteractions().extend([
    pointInteraction, lineInteraction, polygonInteraction,
    circleInteraction, rectangleInteraction,
    selectInteraction, modifyInteraction, translateInteraction,
    snapInteraction]);

var activeInteraction;
document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  if (activeInteraction) {
    activeInteraction.setActive(false);
  }
  if (value == 'point') {
    activeInteraction = pointInteraction;
  } else if (value == 'line') {
    activeInteraction = lineInteraction;
  } else if (value == 'polygon') {
    activeInteraction = polygonInteraction;
  } else if (value == 'circle') {
    activeInteraction = circleInteraction;
  } else if (value == 'rectangle') {
    activeInteraction = rectangleInteraction;
  } else {
    activeInteraction = undefined;
  }
  setActiveEditing(!activeInteraction);
  if (activeInteraction) {
    activeInteraction.setActive(true);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Montserrat", Verdana, sans-serif;
      }
      div.full {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAMAAAC6V+0/AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRF7/r+////JvYf4gAAAAJ0Uk5T/wDltzBKAAAAGElEQVR42mJgwAoYYQCJNWQEh5uPAAIMAP2AAUUBpXchAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");*/
      }
      .ol-zoom a:hover,
      .ol-zoom a:focus {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      };
      #draw {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 45px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      #edit {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.13.1/ol.min.js"></script-->
<!--  version 3.13.1 change library to compare
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.13.1/ol.min.js --this WORK's!!!

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol.min.js This NOT WORK and higher
-->
<select id="draw">
      <option value="select">Select to draw…</option>
      <option value="point">Point</option>
      <option value="line">Line</option>
      <option value="polygon">Polygon</option>
      <option value="circle">Circle</option>
      <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    </select>
    <div id="map" class="full"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this issue in Internet Explorer 9 or older versions of Android? If so, then you need to add a polyfill for `requestAnimationFrame`, as mentioned in the v3.14.0 [release notes](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v3.14.0).

To make sure you have everything needed by OpenLayers, even in old browsers, you should include the following polyfills on your page:

```
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
```

The above snippet is taken from one of the [official examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/).